# LIKE ANY function in HiveQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is there an equivalent for the expression matching below statement in HiveQL?

```
Like ANY ('%XYZ' , '%ABC%')
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, but it seems like the following is the same:

```
column_name LIKE '%XYZ' OR column_name LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Comment: Thanks ben, it is similar. However if we have to run it against, say > 10 strings for example, I was wondering to find a simplified solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from employees where name like 'John%' OR name like '%Fred%';
```

Regex

```
select name from employees where name rlike '^*.xyz$|^*.abc.*$';
```

Comment: select name from employees where name rlike '^*.xyz$|^*.abc.*$';

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rlike(regular-expression) for this.  Which can match for the regular expression. The query can be

where rlike '*abc*|*xyz*'